# How to check if payment is late payment with schedules

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1 is a table containing amortization schedules (Predefined when a loan is created)
PN_NUMBER - Loan ID
SEQUENCE - Order of schedule
Amount - Required amount to pay
Maturity - Due Date

Table 2 is a table containing payments (payers can pay any amount)
Date Paid - Transaction date

table 1

| PN_NUMBER | SEQUENCE | AMOUNT | MATURITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 1 | 10000.00 | 2022-02-02 |
| 112 | 2 | 5000.00 | 2022-02-03 |

table 2

| PN_NUMBER | AMOUNT_PAID | DATE_PAID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 2000.00 | 2022-01-29 |
| 112 | 2000.00 | 2022-01-30 |
| 112 | 2000.00 | 2022-01-31 |
| 112 | 2000.00 | 2022-02-01 |
| 112 | 3000.00 | 2022-02-02 |
| 112 | 1000.00 | 2022-02-03 |
| 112 | 3000.00 | 2022-02-04 |
| 112 | 1000.00 | 2022-03-04 |

The goal here is to get the payment date of the record which satisfied the schedule amount.
See example below

| Sequence | ScheduledAmount | ScheduledMaturity | Status | DatePaid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10000.00 | 2022-02-02 | Ontime | 2022-02-02 |
| 2 | 5000.00 | 2022-02-03 | Late | 2022-02-04 |

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Stack Overflow helps those who help themselves.  It is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with cumulative_paid as
(
    select 
        p.PN_NUMBER,
        p.DATE_PAID,
        p.AMOUNT_PAID,
        sum(p.AMOUNT_PAID) over (partition by PN_NUMBER order by DATE_PAID) as CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT_PAID
    from    
        PAYMENTS p
),

cumulative_owed as 
(
        select
            s.PN_NUMBER,
            s.SEQUENCE,
            s.AMOUNT,
            s.MATURITY,
            sum(s.AMOUNT) over (partition by PN_NUMBER order by MATURITY) as CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT_OWED
        from
            AMORT_SCHEDULE s
)

select
    co.PN_NUMBER,
    co.SEQUENCE,
    max(co.AMOUNT) as SCHEDULED_AMOUNT,
    max(co.MATURITY) as SCHEDULED_MATURITY,
    case 
        when
            min(cp.DATE_PAID) is null
            or min(cp.DATE_PAID) > max(co.MATURITY)
        then 
            'Late'
        else
            'Ontime'
    end as Status,
    min(cp.DATE_PAID) as DATE_PAID
from
    cumulative_owed co
left outer join
    cumulative_paid cp 
on
    co.PN_NUMBER = cp.PN_NUMBER
    and cp.CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT_PAID >= co.CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT_OWED
group by
    co.PN_NUMBER,
    co.SEQUENCE
order by
    co.PN_NUMBER,
    co.SEQUENCE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    t1.SEQUENCE AS Sequence,
    t1.Amount AS ScheduledAmount,
    t1.Maturity AS ScheduledMaturity,
    CASE
        WHEN t1.Amount = COALESCE(SUM(t2.AMOUNT_PAID), 0) THEN 'Ontime'
        WHEN t1.Amount > COALESCE(SUM(t2.AMOUNT_PAID), 0) THEN 'Late'
    END AS Status,
    MAX(t2.DATE_PAID) AS DatePaid
FROM
    table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
    table2 t2 ON t1.PN_NUMBER = t2.PN_NUMBER AND t1.SEQUENCE = t2.SEQUENCE
GROUP BY
    t1.SEQUENCE, t1.Amount, t1.Maturity
ORDER BY
    t1.SEQUENCE;
```